# Is part number a crucial factor when purchasing server hard-drive

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, hpe

I'm doing some research on `HP HDD SAS 900G 6G/s 10K-RPM 2.5"` hard-drives for a purchase order. On Amazon or Ebay there are all kinds of part numbers and/or spare numbers for example `619291-B21 619463-001 619286-004` which add to my confusion.

My question is: how do part number and spare number affect the quality of the product. Should I be worried about part numbers when purchasing server hard-drives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HPE servers part numbers are important. Always check the quickspecs of your server type. There are listed officially supported part numbers.

In case you find HDD which claims to be compatible with your part number found in quickspecs, it should be safe to use (or seller lies...).